# Limit number of choices shown in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a command-line option with a huge number of choices (hundreds) and it clutters up the `--help` output. Is there a way to truncate the *displayed* choices while still allowing the full range to be used?

Tiny example:

```py
parser.add_argument('foo', default=42, choices=[x for x in range(1000)])
```

Comment: a use should just combine it with `less` to make it easier to read.

Comment: Sure, but the wall of text is a pain. I'd like to display it like `{1,2,3...}` but still allow the user to choose any of the original numbrs.

Comment: No.  Choices is best for a modest number.  You could implement the same sort of check with a `type` function.    `metavar` can also be used to replace the choices display  (but not in an error message).

Comment: There's been a bug/issue regarding limiting the choices display, but developers have not come to any sort of concensus on how that should look like.

Comment: Ah, [metavar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar) solves my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/) in a comment, it's possible to use the `metavar` argument ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar)) to override what is displayed by `--help`:

```py
parser.add_argument('foo', choices=[x for x in range(1000)], metavar="{0,1,2,...,999}")
```

If a user provides an invalid argument the error message will still show the complete set of choices.